# What is the difference between 'sponsored by' and 'presented by'?

Tags: terminology

I saw this both of these things on a TV program logo: one is written on at the top, the other at the bottom.

I'm aware that "**sponsored by**" and "**presented by**" are a commercial thing, but what do they mean and how are they different from each other?

Comment: They don't mean anything, nor is there any substantive difference between them. The people who are "sponsors" have little or no editorial input into the shows. They're just glorified advertisers; http://www.alkenmrs.com/soapsrus/coronationstreet/cscadbury.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, "presented by" is the company who owns the show. The presenter is likely to have legal responsibilities for the show.It may also be the person or organisation that is paying for the whole show.

The "sponsors" are those who are supporting the conference financially or in other external ways such as advertising (there may be many sponsors).

For example, Wizcraft company presents so many shows like IIFA. But the sponsors are different like videocon.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if a show is "presented by" a company, they are the only advertiser. Most programs have multiple sponsors/advertisers. Other than that there is little difference. The commercials actually pay the production and/or distribution costs of the show.

Comment: How is this different from "sponsored by?" Also, can you present any evidence for your answer?